# PyQt Progressbar QThread does not work correct

Tags: python, pyqt, progress-bar, qthread, qtcore

I have a problem with my code. My plan is to show the progress of a for loop using a progressbar. My idea was to use Qthread. My code below works somehow, but not 100 percently correct. The progressbar shows the progress of the for loop, but not via a thread i.e. if I try to click more then once on Stop the GUI freezes.
I am not a QtCore expert. Can please someone help me and tell me why it does not work the way I want it to work?

Thanks a lot!

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

#Progressbar
class MyCustomWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyCustomWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)       

        self.progressBar = QtGui.QProgressBar(self)
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,100)
        layout.addWidget(self.progressBar)

    #Update Progressbar
    def onProgress(self, i):
        self.progressBar.setValue(i)
        if self.progressBar.value() >= self.progressBar.maximum():
            self.close()

#Threading Class
class ASA(QtCore.QThread):
    notifyProgress = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def run(self, i):

        #Sends the new information to the Update Function
        self.notifyProgress.emit(i)
        time.sleep(0.01)

#-----------------------------------------#
#Main Function
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
bar = MyCustomWidget()
bar.show()

bar.asa = ASA()
bar.asa.notifyProgress.connect(bar.onProgress)
bar.asa.start()

#For loop for the progressbar
for i in range(105):
    ASA.run(bar.asa, i)
    time.sleep(0.5)  

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop needs to be run inside the thread itself:

```
def run(self):
    #Sends the new information to the Update Function
    for i in range(105):
        self.notifyProgress.emit(i)
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way to do it outside the ASA class? Because my loop contains 200 lines of code.

Comment: I think it is ok to use it the way you showed me. But one question: how do I e.g. set the range of the for loop? Instead of 105 I want that I can hand over a range when I call the progressbar.

Comment: @user3318234 re specify range: this is a separate question, but can you  specify it in your ASA.__init__?

Comment: thanks a lot. I had thought of that, but I have not tried it until now.